# SharePoint 2013 list Date Picker doesn't work in an Infopath form

Tags: 2013, infopath, list-form

I created a new custom list and edited the form within InfoPath.  After customizing the form and publishing it back to the SP 2013 list, the date picker doesn't work.

The few forum posts I reviewed touching on this topic did not provide solutions.

This site collection has Publishing turned on.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how it is not working, specifically? Does it not appear, does it not function correctly?

Comment: The calendar icon  to the right is greyed and wont open the calendar to select a date when you click it. Nor will it let you type a date in the field and save. Acts like it is read-only and wont save the entered date.  The date picker worked in Infopath browser view, but not after publishing back to original list.